# Continous testing and Surefire arg line

Tags: quarkus

I need to add the the following configuration for my testing context (with @QuarkusTest):

```
--add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED
```

So I put it in the Surefire plugin arg-line statement. It works perfectly when I use mvn test command. Unfortunately when using Quarkus test mode, the option seems to be ignored.

Is it possible to pass this option in another way ?
Thanks

**Solution**
The only way I found to get it work in dev and test mode is to add following in pom.xml:

```
<properties>
    <jvm.args>--add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED</jvm.args>
</properties>
```

Quarkus version 3.6.5
Java 17

Comment: Can you try starting dev mode with `mvn quarkus:dev -Dopen-lang-package`?

Comment: Sorry I didn't reply, unfortunately  `-Dopen-lang-package` not working in test/dev mode ;(